# Webpack 4 + Vue + jQuery

Tags: jquery, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-4

I have a project on jQuery, I need to transfer it to Vue.

I'm assembly a project using webpack 4 and I can not find a working recipe for integrating a jQuery into a view on this version of webpack.

Maybe someone, can show me an example, how can this be done?

All recipes, what I can find on the internet - not work in webpack 4.
I'm trying loaders, try edit config.js - nothing works.

Help me, please!

Comment: What do you need jQuery for if you're using Vue?

Comment: Show your example. You probably need to add jquery to webpack config.

Comment: Check my repo, jQuery is integrated https://github.com/syed-haroon/vue-cli3-starter-template

Answer (score 0):

Check my repo, jQuery is integrated here: https://github.com/syed-haroon/vue-cli3-starter-template

And please make sure to install `vue-cli3` may be in latest `node 8` version and do `npm install` and to run the project `npm run serve` (now it's changed and `npm run dev` will not work).

And you can use it this way:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <H1 class="lorem">jQuery Works</H1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import $ from 'jquery';

export default {
  mounted() {
    $('.lorem').addClass('ipsum');
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, i canot run your project.

Comment: @Maksim please make sure to install `vue-cli3` may be in latest `node 8` version and do `npm install` and to run the project `npm run serve` (now it's changed and `npm run dev` will not work).